# SQL Query with complex joins in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I have a table with the following 5 columns:

```
"REPORT NUMBER", "PAGE ID", "ROW NUMBER", "COLUMN NUMBER","VALUE"
```

Below is a sample of 5 of the 1.6MM rows I have in SQL.

```
"580498"    "B000002"   "00500" "01600" "17"    
"580498"    "B000002"   "00600" "02400" "201"    
"580508"    "B000002"   "00500" "01600" "42"    
"580508"    "A000000"   "01000" "00200" "909874"    
"580508"    "A000000"   "01000" "00300" "1432422"
```

Each Page-Row-Column combination is a map to a special value. For Instance Page B000002, row 00500 column 01600 tells me the number of employees for that report number. Other combinations show me revenue, expenses, etc, etc per report number.

I am looking to make a new table with the following columns:

```
"REPORT NUMBER", "EMPLOYEES", "ANOTHER COLUMN", "ANOTHER COLUMN"
"580498"    "17"    ""  ""
"580508"    "42"    ""  ""
```

Where there is just one row for each reoport number. I know it is possible to just keep doing joins, but there are over 150 columns to be added so was hoping there was an alternative way to do this.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select report_number,
       max(value) filter (where Page = 'B000002' and row = '00500' and column = '01600') as num_employees 
rom t
group by report_number;
```